# Can I run animation with css button?

Tags: css

When I click on a button that I have given, I want the button to activate the animation, but I have two animations when I add both, I get an error, how can I solve it :)
I'm doing this animation for dark mode transition effect

```
#drk:active .turtle {
    animation: drag 4s linear;
   -webkit-animation: drag 4s linear alternate; /* Chrome and Safari */
  
   
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 50;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
  }

#drk:active . {
    animation: drag 4s linear;
   -webkit-animation: drag 4s linear alternate; /* Chrome and Safari */
  
   
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 50;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a working code snippet (HTML+CSS), so we can help you based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@keyframes example {
  0%   {background-color: red;}
  25%  {background-color: yellow;}
  50%  {background-color: blue;}
  100% {background-color: green;}
}

#dark:focus{
  /*
  OR
  #dark:active{
  */
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: null -->
```

```html
<button id="dark">TEST</button>
```

Thanks for your answer. I think you do not fully understand my question. I have two animations connected to the same button but not working. My target is to show another animation when switching to dark mode, another when switching to light mode

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code below
I also recommend you to review this link. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

```css
@keyframes example {
  0%   {background-color: red;}
  25%  {background-color: yellow;}
  50%  {background-color: blue;}
  100% {background-color: green;}
}

#dark:focus{
  /*
  OR
  #dark:active{
  */
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

```html
<button id="dark">TEST</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this then

```css
/*DARK MODE*/
@keyframes example {
  0%   {background-color: #000000;}
  50%  {background-color: #FF0000;}
  100% {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
}

.darkmode .mybutton:focus{
  /*
  OR
  #dark:active{
  */
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}


/*WHITE MODE*/
@keyframes example2 {
  0%   {background-color: #FFFFFF;}
  50%  {background-color: #FF0000;}
  100% {background-color: #000000;}
}

.whitemode .mybutton:focus{
  /*
  OR
  #dark:active{
  */
  background-color: #000000;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  animation-name: example2;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="darkmode">
<button class="mybutton">TestLabel Dark Mode</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="whitemode">
<button class="mybutton">TestLabel White mode</button>
</div>
```